# How to read and understand ExtJS Source code?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm programming in ExtJS recently. I can understand the usage of config for components.
But, when someone says to make a custom class by extending existing class to add additional functionality, I get totally confused.

So, my question is -

Is there any tutorial / site that explains the source code and it's meaning and how to customize it to our own implementation ?

Thanks

Comment: mmm... Their website? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/video/17733892 This is not a programming question, SO is for specific questions about code, not general programming guidelines

Answer (score 4):

Sencha has good tutorials for ExtJS. [**They can all be found here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide).

They also have tutorials that define programming *concepts*. The specific one you mentioned that describes "custom classes" to create your own Javascript objects in ExtjS is [**this one**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/class_system).

There are many others in the "Concepts" category of the first linked page above which I found very helpful if you are going to be doing much with ExtJS.